# How should I prevent Ditto from copying passwords from Bitwarden Firefox extension?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, ditto

I've known Ditto to be working well until passwords I copied started appearing. I use BitWarden (premium) and I find the hash values inside the ditto clipboard list.

I use windows 10.

And I mostly use BW firefox extension for copying passwords.

I know there is an `exclude` option in `Ditto>Options`, and thus want to know if there is a way to point to the BW FireFox extension?